# .htaccess redirecting sub domains to sub domains name folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My site structure is as follows:

/
 static/
 www/
   index.html
   img/
 www2/
   index.html
   img/
 www3/
   index.html
   img/

I have this .htaccess that does the following:
According to a subdomain for instance `www.domain.com/index.html` i redirect to the right subdomain folder which is `/www/index.html`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1
</IfModule>
```

It works perfectly when i am accessing the site with `www.domain.com/index.html`
but not without index.html meaning
`www.domain.com/` .

I have tried many condition but non of them seems to work , and if it works it breaks what i have now.
Which condition should i add for redirecting the `www.domain.com/` to `/www/index.html` ?
Thanks

**EDIT**

The error i am receiving is: 
"Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."
meaning i am redirected to the / folder which doesnt contains an index.html.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work `www.domain.com/` What exactly happens? Does your site show? Error? What?

Comment: sorry you are right just edited with the error

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you don't have a directory index set. There is nothing wrong with going directly to the file but apache doesn't consider index.html your index file. And with directory listing turned off you will get that error. You don't need rewrite for that. Use the directive. That should prevent the 403 Forbidden.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Tried that but It doesn't work, still the same error.  because after the rewrite the uri is /index.html and i need it to be the /subdomain/index.html

Comment: put an .htaccess file inside the subdomain folder with the directoryindex in it and try that.